# Get refresh token for Box provider

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm using Boxr gem
[boxr](https://github.com/cburnette/boxr) for my autotests I need to do some manipulation with files and I have created developer token and did some things, after some time developer token was expired. 
BUT on documentation I saw that I can do refresh token before runing tests.

***If you want Boxr to automatically refresh the tokens once the access token becomes invalid you can supply a refresh token, along with your client_id and client_secret, and a block that will get invoked when the refresh occurs.***

```
token_refresh_callback = lambda {|access, refresh, identifier| some_method_that_saves_them(access, refresh)}
client = Boxr::Client.new('zX3UjFwNerOy5PSWc2WI8aJgMHtAjs8T',
                          refresh_token: 'dvfzfCQoIcRi7r4Yeuar7mZnaghGWexXlX89sBaRy1hS9e5wFroVVOEM6bs0DwPQ',
                          client_id: 'kplh54vfeagt6jmi4kddg4xdswwvrw8y',
                          client_secret: 'sOsm9ZZ8L8svwrn9FsdulLQVwDizKueU',
                          &token_refresh_callback)
```

The question is: What the method should be for save refresh token? **"some_method_that_saves_them"**

Comment: I don't understand what is your question?

Comment: How to make refresh token using this function?

Comment: What arguments are passed to provided `token_refresh_callback`?

Comment: I have only generated refresh token, client_id, and client _secret
check also this link https://github.com/cburnette/boxr

Comment: also having issues with this. Wonder if you fixed it?